# Char Pointer array memory allocation

Tags: c++, pointers, static-memory-allocation

How the memory allocation is done for a char pointer array and double pointer.

```
char *s[]={"knowledge","is","power"}; 
char **p;
 p=s;
 cout<<++*p;
```

In the above code output given by compiler is-
 nowledge

My question is just , how the values are assigned to pointer p and how it's incremented.

Comment: The two concepts you need to understand are "array to pointer conversion", which causes `p = s` to be equivalent to `p = &s[0]`, and the precedence/associativity of operators, which causes ``++*p` to be equivalent to `++(*p)`.

Comment: @Peter Both `*` and `++` have the same precedence. What matters is their associativity.

Comment: @DYZ - thanks for that - I was just editing to mention associativity when your comment came in

Comment: @DYZ `++`(suffix) has higher precedence than `*`(dereference), only `++`(prefix) has the same precedence with `*`(dereference). @see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

Comment: @KaiserKatze Surely it is a prefix in `++*p`.

Comment: @DYZ Yeah, I just want to prevent anyone from quoting the remark out of its context.

Answer (score 1):

The operators `++` and `*` have the [same precedence and are both right-to-left-associative](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), which means that the rightmost operator (`*`) is executed first. The value of `*p` is a pointer to the first character of the first string. The operator `++` increments it, making it the pointer to the *second* character of the first string. That's how you get the "nowledge."

Comment: Very useful for those of us still learning C++! So for example,  `p = &s[2]` would give "ower".