# Pointer and array memory

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers

I am confused between the output of the following code:

```
char *s[]={"knowledge","is","power"};
char t[]={"Hello"};
char **p,*q;
p=s;
q=t;
cout<<++*p;
cout<<*p++;
cout<<++*p;
cout<<++*q;
```

Now, the Output is `nowledge nowlegde s I`.

Please explain how the memory allocation is taking place in both arrays.

Comment: Look at the [operator precedence order in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Then, simplify the statements to make sense of them.

Comment: You also have undefined behavior by accessing the arrays using invalid pointer values.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is something you need to be careful with.

Comment: Try this link, under Pointer arithmetics. This should clear up your doubts http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: Very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51904617/9254539

Comment: @FeiXiang Yes but the output for the String "Hello" is taking ASCII Value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *s[] = {"knowledge", "is", "power"};

       ===========================================================
addr1: | 'k' | 'n' | 'o' | 'w' | 'l' | 'e' | 'd' | 'g' | 'e' | 0 |
       ===========================================================

       =================
addr2: | 'i' | 's' | 0 |
       =================

       ===================================
addr3: | 'p' | 'o' | 'w' | 'e' | 'r' | 0 |
       ===================================

       =========================
addr4: | addr1 | addr2 | addr3 |
       =========================

    s: addr4
```

.

```
char *t[] = {"Hello"};

       ===================================
addr5: | 'H' | 'e' | 'l' | 'l' | 'o' | 0 |
       ===================================

       =========
addr6: | addr5 |
       =========

    t: addr6
```

.

```
char **p,**q;
p=s;
q=t;

    p: addr4
    q: addr6
```

.

```
++*p;

     p: addr4
    *p: addr1
  ++*p: addr1 + 1
(!) *p: addr1 + 1
```

.

```
*p++;

     p: addr4
    *p: addr1 + 1
  *p++: addr1 + 1
(!)  p: addr4 + 1
```

.

```
++*p;

     p: addr4 + 1
    *p: addr2
  ++*p: addr2 + 1
(!) *p: addr2 + 1
```

.

```
++*q;

     q: addr6
    *q: addr5
  ++*q: addr5 + 1
(!) *q: addr5 + 1
```

Comment: in *q  why it is not printing "e"?? @Max Vollmer but it is taking H+1= 73+1=74.

Comment: `char t[]={"Hello"};` is something very different from `char *t[]={"Hello"};`. You don't have a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of chars, instead you have a pointer to an array of chars. So when you dereference that pointer, you won't get a pointer to a char array, you get a char. Thus you are incrementing a char, not a pointer.